# How to install qrtools for Python on Mac OSX El Capitan 10.11?

Tags: python, macos, qr-code, zbar

How to install `qrtools` for Python correctly on Mac OSX El Capitan 10.11?

After the installation using `brew install zbar` and `pip install qrtools zbar`, I got a segmentation fault 11 while trying to import `zbar` in Python.

Comment: I have the same problem. Interested in a solution.

Comment: Does `import qrtools` cause a segfault for you?

Comment: Yes, it causes a seg fault

Answer (score 1):

This solution worked for me on 10.10. probably it also works for you: [Zbar + python, crashes on import (OSX 10.9.1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21612908/zbar-python-crashes-on-import-osx-10-9-1)

Comment: check the comment by @aikoven below the linked answer  (`pip install git+https://github.com/npinchot/zbar.git`)