# Installing zbar for Python 2.7 on Mac OS

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, bitcoin, zbar

I am trying to install zbar on Mac OS with Python 2.7 and Anaconda.
I installed zbar with

```
$ brew install zbar
```

Anaconda environmnent shows zbar is installed.
However, when I run the code

```
import zbar
```

in Spyder, the shell returns "Kernel died, restarting" and nothing happens.

Does anybody know what am I missing out on?

Thank you for your help!

PS: I am not persistent on using zbar, an alternative open-source solution which would work would be appreciated as well (also have openCV installed, so image preprocessing is no issue)
Thanks!

Comment: Found a solution, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21612908/zbar-python-crashes-on-import-osx-10-9-1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Zbar + python, crashes on import (OSX 10.9.1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21612908/zbar-python-crashes-on-import-osx-10-9-1)